# Filter through objects array and remove items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects in angularjs looking like this:

```
[
   0: {id: "1", user_id: "1", name: "object1"},
   1: {id: "2", user_id: "1", name: "obejct2"},
   2: {id: "3", user_id: "2", name: "object3"},
]
```

I want to search through the array and remove the items that don't have a specific user_id, stored in another variable. I tried array.filter but didn t work.

Comment: Show your attempt.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question. Do you want to remove second object  with user_id: "1" ?

Comment: I have a select in my php. If I choose a specific user, I want to get only the objects that belongs to that user_id.

Comment: Ok, you are using angularjs, but your question doesn't seem to be angularjs specific. Probably you should remove the tag, but that's just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I would add a nicely concise way:

```
const keepId = '1'
const filtered = data.filter(({ user_id }) => user_id === keepId)
```

Uses:

- [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

---

Also keep in mind that `filter()` returns a **new** array, keeping the original in tact. If you want to alter the original array, you would have to use something like [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: That made it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`array.filter` is the correct approach. You probably miss-implemented it.

See this snippets, it filters out all entries with a `user_id` different from `1`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter for documentation

```js
const data = [
   {id: "1", user_id: "1", name: "object1"},
   {id: "2", user_id: "1", name: "object3"},
   {id: "3", user_id: "2", name: "object3"},
]
const filteredData = data.filter((item) => {
   return item.user_id === '1';
})

console.log(filteredData)
```

Comment: Opinion - OP knows about `array.filter` and as you mentioned that there must be a miss-implementation. For an answer, we must first know the implementation which is already requested in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you store the selected value into 'selectedUserId' variable.

You can achieve your goal by:

```js
let selectedUserId = '1';

let data = [
   {id: "1", user_id: "1", name: "object1"},
   {id: "2", user_id: "1", name: "object3"},
   {id: "3", user_id: "2", name: "object3"},
]
let output = data.filter(item => item.user_id === selectedUserId)

console.log(output)
```